# PHP: Serializing/Deserializing hidden array in form

Tags: php, forms, serialization, hidden-field

Working with PHP 5.5.9

I'm trying to send a hidden serialized array to a form. I have the form and the action script in the same file, using

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
```

I initialize the array at the beginning of the file:

```
 <?php $sports = array("Basketball", "Football", "Handball");?>
```

I add an ok button to my form:

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="serializedData" value="<?php echo serialize($sports);?>">
    <input type="submit" name="okButton" value="OK"><br>
</form>
```

Now I'm trying to deserialize the hidden array when the user presses the ok Button. I want the code also to print the contents of the array

```
if(isset($_POST['okButton'])) {
   $sports_new = unserialize($_POST['serializedData']);

   // Show array
   for($i = 0; $i < count($sports_new); $i++) {
                    print $sports_new[$i]."<br/>";
   }
```

But nothing is shown. I guess that the input hidden element of my form does not get any data. But the $sports array is initialized at the beginning of the file. Why does it not get serialized? 
Or does my problem rely on the deserializing code?

Comment: What does return `$_POST['serializedData']` alone?

Comment: Step 1: Go check the generated HTML code – doesn’t that look wrong to you? Step 2: Go research how data that you put into an HTML context needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I followed your hints.
Needed to convert the htmlentities before:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="serializedData" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($sports));?>">
```